# Don't allow zalgo in the "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, unicode

Today I saw this in the "Hot Network Questions"

[image: Zalgo text in HNQ]

I know that questions with zalgo are allowed, that's not my point here: my point is that I believe we should not allow this kind of text in the "Hot Network Questions" (or in the "Featured on Meta" box, or anywhere else except in *the question itself*). It looks bad.

In this specific case it could be only *"Operation Unzalgo"* and then, if the user clicks on the link, the actual question appears (with zalgo or whatever).

Comment: Unicode ruins everything.

Comment: `...  It looks bad.` That's subjective, this title is not really that horrible. Are there any other (non-aesthetic) reasons to disable zalgo?

Comment: Unicode is why we can't have N͆̿͘iͣ̅ͮͭ̍c̵̎̃̓̍͌ͧ̌eͩ̇́ ̍̉̅̈ͤͩ͏t͋̀̕h͊ͣ̓͂ͮ̚í̶̽̅ņ́̑͐̑̇̑ĝ̨̿̾ͫs̄ͤ̑̑͆ͪ
̇̌ͨ͒҉

Comment: @defaultlocale it has the potential to obscure the titles above and below, and it might end up breaking the list layout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because h̷eͤ͛̈́̂̔̽̾ ͤ̀̈́ͨ̂̌c̒ͦ̇oͣ͐̊͊̄m̧͐ͮ̅e̽̄̇͒͑͛͂͟sͬͫ̀̕.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is a "problem" worth spending time on.

As you acknowledged, aesthetics are subjective; what "looks bad" to one won't bother another. In that case though (really it's not bad faith on my end), unless I don't know something, Zalgo is static? So **it's not as disruptive as a blinking label**, an emboldened one, a colored one, etc.

Basically it looks like a couple more pixels (to me, again) in a list partially hidden on the right. And it's not like all titles are Zalgo either; it's one (at the moment), displayed randomly between 99 other questions.

Finally **it doesn't seem frequent enough to warrant an additional treatment**. How often does Zalgo make it to HNQ? I think in 18 months of using SE, that's the first time (maybe second) I've seen one.

Comment: Its actually a pretty tame case of diacritic abuse. There's one post on SE that... breaks stuff pretty bad since its diacritics yaaaaaaay high